# script to update XML file data

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to update value field by searching the avp name in below .xml file .

```
 <avp name="CC-Request-Type" value="1"> </avp>
  <avp name="CC-Request-Number" value="0"> </avp>
  <avp name="Subscription-Id">
  <avp name="Subscription-Id-Type" value="0"></avp>
  <avp name="Subscription-Id-Data" value="4081234567"></avp>
  <avp name="Framed-IP-Address" value="0xXXXXX"> </avp>
```

I need to search row has "Framed-IP-Address" update value filed 0xXXXXX to 0xYYYYY

Please let me know how to do using sed or AWK or shell script any input to do this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The right tool for this is something that is *XML-aware*.

XSLT (via `xsltproc`) or any general purpose scripting language at your disposal (Python, Ruby, Perl, node.js, even PHP-CLI) are examples of suitable tools to modify XML. sed or awk or bash script are examples of unsuitable ones.

Here's an XSLT-based solution

```
<!-- modify-Framed-IP-Address.xsl -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="avp[@name = 'Framed-IP-Address']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">0xYYYYY</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

used as

```
xsltproc modify-Framed-IP-Address.xsl input.xml -o output.xml
```

will replace the attribute and save the result to `output.xml`.

If you don't want to use XSLT, use a scripting language you know. A Python-based solution, for example, would be in the same order of less-then-10 lines of code for such a simple task. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python) to get an idea on how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this sed command,

```
sed '/<avp name=\"Framed-IP-Address\"/s~value=\"[^"]*\"~value="0xYYYYY"~g' file
```

Through awk,

```
awk '/<avp name=\"Framed-IP-Address\"/{sub(/value=\"[^"]*\"/,"value=\"0xYYYYY\"")}1' file
```